# relation between first kind Chebyshev poly and second kind Chebyshev poly

Tags: chebyshev-polynomials

How do you prove following relation between Chebyshev poly of first kind and Chebyshev poly of second kind:
$$dT_n(x)/dx=nU_{n-1}(x)$$

Comment: Since both sequences of polynomials have nice recursions, one idea is to do this by induction. Have you tried?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean...you mean indicator function?

Answer (score 3):

Since
$T_n(x)
=\cos(n\arccos(x))
$
and
$U_n(x)
=\frac{\sin((n+1)\arccos(x))}{\sin(\arccos(x))}
$,

$\begin{array}\\
T_n'(x)
&=-(n\arccos(x)))'\sin(n\arccos(x))\\
&=-n\frac{-1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\sin(n\arccos(x))\\
&=\frac{n}{\sqrt{1-(\cos(\arccos(x))^2}}\sin(n\arccos(x))
\qquad\text{(this is a sort of sneaky part)}\\
&=\frac{n\sin(n\arccos(x))}{\sin(\arccos(x))}\\
&=nU_{n-1}(x)
\end{array}
$

Comment: I see...is there a proof for conditions Tn(x)=cos(narccos(x)) and Un(x)=sin((n+1)arccos(x))sin(arccos(x)) you used? Or it is theorem that people can directly use it without proving?

Comment: These follow from the recurrences.